# SwiftUI ObservableObject + @Published equivalent in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, state, swiftui

I developed an iOS app in SwiftUI, and now need to port it to Android, and decided to try Flutter. After overcoming super verbose and/or ugly nested widgets, I got stuck on state management. In SwiftUI:

```
class MySharedObj : ObservableObject {
  @Published var someVar = 0
}
```

Now I can simply drop "@ObservedObject var obj:MySharedObj" in ANY views, and whenever the someVar is changed anywhere, all views "observing" this object are updated automatically. Is there something equivalent in Flutter? Currently I manage a list of "listeners" manually as follows:

```
class ObservableObject { 
  List<State> _listeners = [];
  ObservableObject subscribe(State state) { _listeners.add(state); return(this); }
  ObservableObject unsubscribe(State state) { _listeners.remove(state); return(this); }
  ObservableObject notify() { _listeners.forEach((l) => l.setState((){})); return(this); }
}
class MySharedObj : ObservableObject {
  int _someVar = 0;
  int get someVar => _someVar;
  void set someVar(int v) { _someVar = v; notify(); }
}

class SomeView1State extends State<SomeView1> {
  @override initState(){widget.obj.subscribe(this);super.initState();}
  @override dispose(){widget.obj.unsubscribe(this);super.dispose();}
}
...
```

This sort of works, but it's ugly and again verbose (it seems to be Android's theme).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at the provider package. There's a great discussion of it [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).